# Is cos(t+1) in this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The solution set of the differential equation
\begin{gather*}
\frac{d^2 y}{d t^2} = -y(t)
\end{gather*}
is equal to the span of two linearly independent solutions,
for example $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$.

$\cos(t+1)$ satisfies the equation, so $\cos(t+1)$ is a linear combination of $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$.

But is it? How can I write $\cos(t + 1)$ as a linear combination of $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know the trigonometric angle addition formulas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write $\cos(t + 1)$ as a linear combination of $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$?

By the [angle sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), $\cos(t+1)=\cos(1)\cos(t)-\sin(1)\sin(t)$.